# Multiple parents for document in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, document, umbraco

I need to be able to:

- connect **one news item to multiple news** items groups.
- Additionally to that the **order of the items in each group is important** and the content editors need to be able to change the order at any time.

SO basically what I'm looking for is a structure like this:

- News group **1**

  - **News item 1**
  - News item 2
  - News item 3
- News group **2**

  - News item 6
  - News item 5
  - **News item 1**

I have already looked into relations, but it seems that its not possible to influence the order.

Also editing the order should preferably be possible through the default umbraco **sort** functionality (Right click in the content tree and then select sort).

So I think the easiest way would be if I can have multiple parents for a document, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to solve this by standard umbraco functionality, but the downloadable umbraco package **uComponents** contains a control called **Multi Node Tree Picker** that allows you to do just what I wanted.

More details can be found here:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/19558-Multiple-parents-for-document

And here is the documentation for the control:
http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiNodeTreePicker&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in the past by creating a "reference" Document Type that simply points to the content item that I want to copy.  Generally, the reference type has its own template but can use the same macros by adding a property "IsReference".  Then I edit the macros to check for IsReference and if it is a reference, I get the reference Content Item, if it's not, then get the currentPage.

I realize its not exactly what you're looking for, but it allow for all the sorting you want and technically the content is still in one place only.

There is no way to do multiple parents in Umbraco like you're thinking that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, found another solution as described in my answer.